# Why is the browser function crashing my R session?

Tags: r

So, every time I try to use `browser()` in R it crashes. Im not sure what exactly is going on. For example, even in the very simple function below, when I run `fun(2)` my R studio crashes. Im using a Mac Version 10.15.7 Catalina... and my R version is 4.0.2.

```
fun <- function(x){
  browser()
  x+1
}
fun(2)
```

Any idea what is going on here? I used to use `browser()` quite regularly to check my functions... but now Im not sure what is happening?

Comment: Tested on BigSur R 4.0.3, it is working fine

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. My friend tested this on BigSur 4.0.3 and it works for him as well... maybe I should update

Comment: Works for me on Cataline 10.15.7 and R version 4.0.2 (what are the chances we happen to be on the same version, right?). It functions both in a terminal from homebrew and in RStudio.

Comment: hmmm... the plot thickens... now im really confused

Answer (score 0):

To anyone running into this issue (as I did), and if you are using RStudio as your IDE: try **updating RStudio**.

1. In the toolbar *Help* > *Check for Updates*. This will tell you if you are on the latest version
2. If you are not up to date, download the last version from the RStudio website and install it

Also, make sure you are on the latest R version with `R --version`, and if needed run a quick `sudo apt-get install r-base`.